# Laravel 5: jQuery Typeahead gives error status 500 on page load (Missing argument)

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, typeahead.js

Everything else works fine, when I search for a subreddit (category) and submit it to the database, no problem there.

But when I first load the `post/create` page, I get `STATUS 500` on this route `http://localhost/reddit/public/data/subreddits`

I'm not sure what I've done wrong considering that it works.

routes

```
Route::get('data/subreddits', 'PostsController@getSubreddits');
Route::get('data/subreddits/{QUERY}', 'PostsController@getSubreddits');
```

PostsController.php

```
public function create()
{
    $subreddits = Subreddit::lists('name', 'id')->toArray();

    return view('post/create')->with('subreddits', $subreddits);
}

public function getSubreddits($query) {
        $results = Subreddit::select('id', 'name')->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')->get();
        return Response::json($results);
}
```

Javascript in `create.blade.php`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var subreddits = new Bloodhound({
                datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
                queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
                prefetch: 'http://localhost/reddit/public/data/subreddits',
                remote: {
                    url: 'http://localhost/reddit/public/data/subreddits/%QUERY',
                    wildcard: '%QUERY'
                }
            });

            $('#remote .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
                name: 'name',
                display: 'name',
                source: subreddits
            });

            $('#remote .typeahead').bind('typeahead:select', function(ev, suggestion) {
                $('.subreddit_id').val(suggestion.id);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Error

> Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controller\PostsController::getSubreddits()

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: It showed me a new error now `Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\PostsController::getSubreddits()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @mimo has answered you need to make your `query` a optional parameter.

```
Route::get('data/subreddits/{query?}', 'PostsController@getSubreddits');
```

Also you need to pass a default value to your `query` parameter in `getSubreddits`

```
public function getSubreddits($query = '') {
    $results = Subreddit::select('id', 'name')->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')->get();
    return Response::json($results);
}
```

Also if there are only few results you can sent all the data if no query parameter is passed.

```
public function getSubreddits($query = '') {
    $q = Subreddit::select('id', 'name')
    if ($query) {
        $q->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%');
    }
    return Response::json($q->get());
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks man. It works. I guess I misunderstood @mimo - and I still needed a default value for `$query` parameter. I removed the duplicate route as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your first route has no parameter but you call a function that needs one. If you delete the row the error should be removed.

```
Route::get('data/subreddits/{QUERY?}', 'PostsController@getSubreddits');
```

Will call the function even when there is no query.

Comment: I am still getting the same error after removing that route.

Comment: Then please post your route.php file and your `getSubreddits` function.

Comment: I posted that code in my original post just have a look at it.

Comment: But if you just have `Route::get('data/subreddits/{QUERY}', 'PostsController@getSubreddits');` it should solve the error because then there is no url like `data/subreddits`

Comment: well it's not the same error, it's `404 page not found` because I had just removed it.

Comment: Okay, so the client is sending a request with empty query to your server (maybe when he is building up the page). What happens if you write a function for your `data/subreddits` that returns nothing?